# Rails, ActiveSupport::Notifications - return metrics in response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, metrics, activesupport

I am working on tracking basic metric data for requests, such as how much time was spent in the DB, rendering JSON, etc... for developer instrumentation/analysis so we can find and fix slow/bad code.

I have a simple

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe /process_action.action_controller/ do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
  Rails.logger.info event
end
```

where I can send the metrics to the log file (I think this is how Rails 3+ generates logfiles already).

However, I would also like to return some of the metrics back in the response header so that each request can see how long it took in the DB vs generating views, etc...

As to "why" I want to do this, it's because my application's security is such that developers don't have access to the metrics themselves so using the response headers is a cheap way to allow developers to start viewing some basic metrics to help them fix slow code.  I understand some will tell me this is a bad practice, and I don't disagree, but I need to do it for now.

The specific issue is that when this subscriber is finished, the response seems to be finished and I can't add the metrics to the headers.

My thoughts are that an `after_filter` in the controller can be used for this, but I'm struggling with how to access the `ActiveSupport::Notifications` event that I subscribed to...as far as I know, there's no global/central location where I can retrieve these events from.

I have read the API and Rails guides, and they didn't help much on this issue.

Anyone know how to access the subscribed events before the response is sent back to the client so I can attach metrics to the headers?